# Why does this multi threaded parallel program executes close to sequential time?

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpool, apple-m1

In the program below, i schedule a small number of threads, each thread executing a CPU-bound long-running single-threaded computation which does not use any locks and saturates a core of Apple M1. I use less threads than physical cores.

The program, when `CONCURRENCY=8` executes in 26 seconds for 8 threads and when `CONCURRENCY=1` in 4 seconds for 1 thread. I do not understand this huge gap.

There is nothing else running on the machine. Temperature is low, plugged in.

I can confirm i see 8 cores in use, i see CPU at `790%` for this Java process.

The computation function here is just a dummy one, not the actual computation i use, but something that does reproduce the problem.

I would expect that the program will take roughly the same amount of time, regardless of how many threads i use (as long as `CONCURRENCY <= 8` for instance, and I have 10 cores on Apple M1).

However, it takes much more time with more threads, and it is very close to the same performance (time) as if i executed the computation sequentially 8 times one after another on a single core.

In reality i have a different computation of course, this is only about the pattern used with this thread pool and what could be wrong.

Pinning computation to cores does not help significantly with this.

The same type of results on i7 and on Apple M1.

I only tested on MBP laptops so far. On Apple M1 and since even between 1 thread and 2 threads there is a huge gap, i think that thermal throttling or power throttling cannot play a big factor.

```
class ProblemWithParallelismTest {
    private static final int CONCURRENCY = 8;

    @SneakyThrows
    @Test
    void evaluate() {
        var latch = new CountDownLatch(CONCURRENCY);
        var executorService = newFixedThreadPool(CONCURRENCY);
        for (int m = 0; m < CONCURRENCY; m++) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                computation();
                latch.countDown();
            });
        }
        latch.await();
    }

    private static void computation() {
        long n = (long) Math.pow(10, 7);
        var sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += LongStream.range(1, 9).boxed().limit(n).map(l -> new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(l))).distinct().count();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Re, "...executes in 26 seconds..." Is that 26 seconds of real time? or is that 26 seconds of CPU time? It should be no surprise if the program uses almost eight times as much CPU time when you ask it to do eight times as much work. How are you measuring the time? It's no surprise if the CONCURRENCY=8 version uses a little bit _less_ than eight times as much CPU if the main thread incurs some extra overhead (initializing the heap and other JVM resources, creating eight worker threads, etc.)

Comment: it is physical time, it is way faster with 1 thread than 4 or 8 threads. Are you able to test it?

Comment: How do you run the test exactly? What is the JDK version and JVM arguments?

Comment: run from Intellij with junit5, java17

Comment: please see the answer as to more details. I think i answered the question as put, but for my original computation the problem still remains. I have it for many months

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that when i pin the computation to the cores, the above does scale horizontally as expected in threads and the time is the same from 1 core to 8 cores.

This does not happen on the original computation, but it does on this one. I cannot share the original computation.

So this proves that the throttling cannot be a cause.

The original computation does fill 790% of CPU (8 cores), and no locking issues.

On the original computation, with pinning and all, still

```
    1 thread  => 5s  physical time
    2 threads => 10s physical time
    4 threads => 34s physical time
    8 threads => 83s physical time
```

Here is the program that does scale horizontally (has same time to execute from 1 thread to 8 threads), with the dummy computation:

```
final class PinnedThreadsParallelismTest {
    private static final int CONCURRENCY = 8;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        var latch = new CountDownLatch(CONCURRENCY);
        var executorService = newFixedThreadPool(CONCURRENCY);
        for (int m = 0; m < CONCURRENCY; m++) {
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                try (var lock = AffinityLock.acquireLock()) {
                    if (lock.cpuId() > 0) {
                        System.out.println("locked on " + lock.cpuId());
                        computation();
                        latch.countDown();
                        System.out.println("countDown");
                    } else {
                        latch.countDown();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        latch.await();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static void computation() {
        long n = (long) Math.pow(10, 7);
        var sum = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            sum += LongStream.range(1, 9).boxed().limit(n).map(l -> new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(l))).distinct().count();
        }
    }
}
```